# React Native TopTabNavigator Icon is not showing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to simply add an Icon to TopTabNavigator but for some reason its not showing, I've done research and I've seen it might be because showIcon is set to false but it didn't change anything, However I do see other options like activeTintColor.

Here is my code:

```
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  
  <TopTab.Navigator
    navigationOptions= {{
      tabBarLabel:"Settings",
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-creates" size={20}/>
      )
    }}
    tabBarOptions= {{ 
      showIcon: true ,
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63'
    }}
  
  >
      <TopTab.Screen name="Settings" component={SecondComponent}/>
      <TopTab.Screen name="RealSettings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </TopTab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
 );
}
```

[image: Refrence Image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the import

add

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
```

also I think you got the name wrong
its "ios-create" not "ios-creates"

```js
  <Icon name="ios-create" size={20}/>
```

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Comment: you're right I changed that but still, the icon is not showing

Comment: I mite not have installed react native vector icons correctly share you package JSON